# How do you resize background image with window

Tags: css, background, background-image

I am working on my wife's business website. There is a background image right under the menu bar on every page. Please see invisionbilling.com/stackoverflow for the picture I would like to use (it's under the background image). I want this image to resize while keeping the same ratio all the way down to responsive. I have something currently that is sort of working but I can't get the height right. It cuts off the picture on desktop view but as I reduce the window it starts to come into view more correctly. However, once you get to a certain window size it stops adjusting and just starts to cut off the right side of the image. How do I get the height to properly adjust and also adjust it all the way down to responsive without cutting off. Thanks for your help!

CSS

```
.breadcrumb_area {
background: url("http://invisionbilling.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2018/07/Background-Photo-Updated.jpg");
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1) inset;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
padding: 60px 0;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Your question sounds like it can't be done. You can't cover all of the viewport with the image and yet keep the h/w ratio of the image. But you're probably looking for `contain` instead of `cover`.

Comment: Perhaps I did word it wrong. I do understand that the height and width will have to change, I was just saying I didn't want it to lose it's quality. Since this issue deals with the window reducing size, the quality shouldn't be an issue. I'm just looking to have the image viewable on all window sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be fine if you just switch out your breadcrumb area to have a background size:contain, and set background-repeat:no-repeat.

```
.breadcrumb_area {
    background-image: url(http://invisionbilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Vision-V5.jpg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1) inset;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    padding: 60px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 295px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan. That almost works perfectly! The only issue is when I get down to mobile, it cuts off the top of the picture, but I am thinking this is because of the responsive menu which I haven't worked on yet.